# Equipment & Software for video bridge (video link) event

Tags: video, audio, webvideos, broadcasting

I need to create a **portable setup for events** built around a **video bridge**:

- The performer is abroad the audience & presenters are in-house
- The performer needs to see the audience & presenters on screen
- The performer will be on screen in-house, visible to the audience & presenters
- The event needs to be broadcasted over the internet simultaneously
- we also need to have the separate video & audio from the audience, presenters and performer feeds recorded for later editing

**So the questions are:**

1. What video equipment makes sense? What cameras, in particular?
2. What sound equipment makes sense? What mikes - and what board... and what else?
3. I'm presuming a dedicated computer for this. What computer makes sense? What other equipment along those lines?
4. What software makes sense? In particular, should we stick with skype to bring the performer in? Google hangouts? Is there something better?
5. Any other advice, recommendations, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question it too broad. Perhaps you should narrow it down a bit. Or you should contact a professional video studio and tell them your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Any advice?  In the end, we do need to find answers to all these things.

Comment: Should I break it up into a series of specific questions?  And also - do you have professional video studios you'd recommend contacting?

Comment: I would search for a video studio that already does what you want. Is this a music performance? Find a studio that has already done it for example.

Comment: Yes these are multiple questions. 1)The distance between presenter and audience 2)The live internet streaming. 3)The interaction between presenter and audience

Comment: 1) It's not a music performance - it's a new interactive nonprofit multinational poetry initiative.  I don't know that anyone HAS done exactly this before.   ...AND 2) Do you think I should repost this as several different posts? Are there other forums you might also recommend? I appreciate the response, we really need some help figuring this out!